# How can I vary shuffle rhythm in recording with Reason?

Tags: software, rhythm, production, reason

I've been handed a few audio tracks from a local beginning artist. I'm struggling with various shuffle rhythms from the artist on guitar. I'm tasked with writing accompanying tracks (piano, strings, etc.) on the computer.

I have broken down shuffle rhythm in separate lanes, as such:

[image: shuffle1]

The main problem I have is that, for each additional instrument, with the current setup I will need to make 3 lanes each to account for the varying degrees of shuffle (with respective ReGroove patches A1, A2, A3). Is there a smarter way of doing this with Reason?

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no way to automate the groove channel parameters, nor the selected groove channel for a track. I'm assuming the song changes between straight and triplet feel, you could always quantise your notes accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by the [comment from GavinH](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/26793/how-can-i-vary-shuffle-rhythm-in-recording-with-reason#comment41467_26793):

> To my knowledge, there is no way to automate the groove channel parameters, nor the selected groove channel for a track. I'm assuming the song changes between straight and triplet feel, you could always quantise your notes accordingly.

I have found that there is indeed not a way to do this without breaking down the sequenced notes between several tracks, one for each Groove channel in Reason.